# Running a Batch fille with -- Parameters via Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameters, arguments

[Screenshot Shortcut Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W15RJ.png)
I'm trying to run a batch file. Via explorer this batch file is run with the following arguments:

```
"C:\Appz\PR Tech\Program.bat" --appId primeVisitKiosk --user onthaal
```

How do I translate this to PowerShell with start-process?

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the quotes that have to be passed to cmd:

```bsh
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/C `"C:\Appz\PR Tech\Program.bat`" --appId primeVisitKiosk --user onthaal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sh
Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/C C:\Appz\Program.bat --appId primeVisitKiosk --user onthaal"
```

Comment: Thanks Philip, I tried it, but my arguments has spaces in it, which i forgot to mention. The path of the bat file = C:\appz\PR Tech\program.bat ... I tried single and double quotes , but it errors on A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument C:\Appz\PR

Answer (score 0):

Phillip's `Start-Process` answer is close. This is how it should be called with that command:

```
Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/C", "C:\appz\PR Tech\program.bat", "--appId", "primeVisitKiosk", "--user", "onthaal"
```

`Start-Process` is mainly useful if you want to use the `-WindowStyle` or `-Wait` parameters.

Alternately, you can use the call operator:

```
& "C:\Appz\PR Tech\Program.bat" --appId primeVisitKiosk --user onthaal
```

Or like so:

```
cmd.exe /C "`"C:\appz\PR Tech\program.bat`" --appId primeVisitKiosk --user onthaal"
```